# Woocomerce añadir dirección de envío a productos virtuales

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

En un cliente tengo que realizar una promoción de Woocomerce para que los productos no tengan gastos de envio. Debido a que ya hay un plugin que gestiona los envios con otra promoción de "gratis para pedidos de más de 60€", no me deja aplicar otro envio gratuito especifico para esta promoción que tiene su propia landing page ( cosas de la gente de marketing), el caso es que al marcar los productos como virtuales no se aplica ningún gasto de envío que es lo que yo buscaba pero el problema surge cuando se mandan los detalles del pedido en los emails de notificación. No aparece la dirección de envio.
He solucionado esta primera parte con el siguiente codigo:

```
/*Add shipping to virtual order*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_true', 50 );
```

Con esto consigo que en el checkout aparezca la opción de enviar a una dirección diferente (aparte de la dirección de facturación que sale por defecto), la dirección de envío aparece en woocomerce order details correctamente pero no se envía en los emails de notificación.
Esta es la plantilla de PHP que he copiado en mi tema hijo en:

woocommerce/templates/email/email-addresses.php

Tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
/**
 * Email Addresses
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-addresses.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates\Emails
 * @version 3.9.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';
$address    = $order->get_formatted_billing_address();
$shipping   = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();

?><table id="addresses" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 40px; padding:0;" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border:0; padding:0;" valign="top" width="50%">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

            <address class="address">
                <?php echo wp_kses_post( $address ? $address : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
                <?php if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
                    <br/><?php echo wc_make_phone_clickable( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
                    <br/><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </address>
        </td>
        <?php if ( ! wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && $order->needs_shipping_address() && $shipping ) : ?>
            <td style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; padding:0;" valign="top" width="50%">
                <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

                <address class="address"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $shipping ); ?></address>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Creo que la clave está en esta linea:

```
if ( ! wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && $order->needs_shipping_address() && $shipping ) :
```

Podéis indicarme qué tengo que poner para que salga la dirección de envío en las notificaciones de email?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de mucho investigar encontré la solución en estos dos sitios:

https://docs.wpdebuglog.com/plugin/woocommerce/4.0.0/filter/woocommerce_order_needs_shipping_address/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55466255/always-display-shipping-address-in-woocommerce-email-notifications

El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:

```
/*Add shipping to virtual order*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_true', 50 );

function enviar_direccion_productos_virtuales( $needs_address, $hide ) {
    $needs_address = true;
    return $needs_address;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_needs_shipping_address', 'enviar_direccion_productos_virtuales', 10, 2 );
```

Si queréis ver las capturas de pantalla del código ya funcionando en Woocomerce os dejo un enlace:

https://www.creandowp.es/anadir-direccion-de-envio-productos-virtuales-de-woocommerce/